# PHP multidimensional array search key by value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example a multidimensional `array` like an example below

```
$arr = array(

 [H1] => array(
            "name" => "A"
            "title" => "T1"
      )
 [H2] => array(
           "name" => "B"
           "title" => "B1"
      )
)
```

Let's say I would like to search `name` which equals to `A` in `$arr` and if it's matched, the searching should return the key which is `H1`

How can I do that in php ?

I tried `array_keys($arr, "A")` but it returns me with an array instead of the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help -

```
$arr = array(

 'H1' => array(
            "name" => "A",
            "title" => "T1",
      ),
 'H2' => array(
           "name" => "B",
           "title" => "B1",
      )
);

// Generate a new array with 'keys' and values in 'name'
$new = array_combine(array_keys($arr), array_column($arr, 'name'));

// Search in that new array
$search = array_search('A', $new);

var_dump($search);
```

**Output**

```
string(2) "H1"
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/446889)

Another simple way would be -

```
$serach= false;
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
   if($val['name'] == 'A') {
       $search= $key;
       break;
   }
}
var_dump($search);
```